# Finding the domain of a composite function given one of the functions and the domain of the other one.

Tags: calculus

$f$ and $g$ are functions such that 
$f(x)=g(\sqrt{25-x^2})$
What should be the domain of function $f$ if the domain of $g$ is $(-3,3)$?

---

My attempt:

The domain of $\sqrt{25-x^2}$ is $[-5,5]$.
$$-3 < \sqrt{25-x^2} < 3$$
and I solve for each side and get
$|x|<4$ and $|x|>4$ (this second one, $|x|>4$, can't be right)
Now I'm confused because the domain of $f(x)$ is the intersection of $|x|<4$ and $|x|>4$ but they don't intersect.

Comment: Please use latex for the maths.. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hmm, I squared both sides and got 25 minus x squared is less than 9. I rearranged the terms and got x squared is greater than 16 and then I took the square root of both sides. I clearly did something wrong, do you know what that is?

Answer (score 1):

$-3 < \sqrt{25-x^2} < 3 \to 0 \leq 25-x^2 < 9 \to 16 < x^2 \leq 25 \to 4 < |x| \leq 5 \to x \in [-5,-4)\cup (4,5] = \text{Dom(f)}$

Comment: Thank you!! How did you get 0 in the second step? You squared all sides to get rid of the square root so 3 squared is 9 but -3 squared is 0?

Comment: @MMAA  Observe that $\sqrt{25 - x^2} \geq 0 > -3$, so you can think of the first inequality as $0 \leq \sqrt{25 - x^2} < 3$.